# What does "area of physics or chemistry" mean in a graduate application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

On the application form (for Max Planck institute), there is a section which says "Please write a short summary of the area of physics or chemistry you find most interesting".

I am not sure what do they exactly mean by "area of physics or chemistry". Should I write a summary of the general field of my interests i.e. condensed matter physics or about the research topic on which on want to work i.e. phase transitions?

Comment: I wouldn't neglect either the general or the specific. If you are too general you might not seem focused. If you are too specific there might not be a good fit. Just enough.

Comment: I am not sure the title correctly describes the essence of the question here.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov, I'm not sure why you object to the title. You can edit, of course, or make a specific suggestion. I don't have a problem with it as is, actually.

Comment: @Buffy the question isn't really about _Max Planck institute_, it is about a specific question on a PhD application, that is presumably why DmitrySavostyanov objects. The OP would probably benefit from a more general title, since it will surely attract more attention

Comment: @user2768, it seems to me that the Institute is relevant here if it is an application to them.

Comment: @Buffy _Please write a short summary of the area of physics or chemistry you find most interesting_ could appear on any application, not just an application for Max Planck institute, so answers independent of that institute are surely relevant. Nonetheless, an answer specific to the institute will probably be more useful to the OP (assuming someone is able to provide such an answer)

Comment: @Buffy I do not think that awareness of PhD programs in Max Planck is necessary or sufficient to answer the actual question, hence my comment. Also, the application forms probably differ from one Max Planck Institute to another. OP should ideally specify which Max Planck Institute they apply to.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you guys discuss the answer to this question instead of discussing the title. By the way, thank you for the suggestions for the appropriate title.

Comment: Almost all the Max Planck Institutes ask this question. But all the other programs (as much as I know) ask for "what are your research interests" instead of "a summary of the field of interests". I think these two are different.

Comment: You need to explain what you are interested in ie "I am interested in examining the Higgs-Boson" or "I want to take S. Hawking's work on string theory in the direction of X", what else do you think they are asking...

Comment: Have you called the Institute and what did they tell you?

Comment: @LuqmanSaleem A good title is worth discussing if it gets you better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you should write about what you want specifically want to study. Anybody can write a page or two about a general branch of either discipline—but that wouldn't help an admissions committee decide if they wanted to hire you or not. A page or two (or some other length, if listed in the question) about your particular research interests would be much more valuable to a committee.