# PhD application question: "Why do you want to join my research group?"

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

Whenever somebody asks me "why are you interested in joining my research group", I find myself helpless. What are the usual points or aspects I should talk about in reply of this question?

Comment: Well, why are *you* interested in this group and not another? Have you done your homework and figured out what kind of research the group is engaged in?

Comment: @Anyon First of all your name is very fascinating. There is a group working on models of fractional quantum Hall effects, and I want to work in that group. Why do I want to join that? Because they are doing simulations of many-body systems. I love simulations. Now, I do not understand what things should I write on motivation letter. Should I write about simulations? Should I write about why I love simulations?

Comment: You have to decide what you want to write to represent YOU... This is also, basically, the thrust of a similar question here : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/118190/72855

Comment: @Luqman: Okay, so say that thing then.  If you love simulations, tell them that.  Tell them *why* you love simulations, etc.

Comment: Advice: ‘because you have money’ doesn’t work like 99% of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, what the potential advisor is asking you to show is that you've "done your homework" before applying. Why do you want to apply to Prof. X's group? What is it about their research that is attractive to you? Why do you think you'd fit in to the group? If you just send a generic email that inquires about positions and don't have an outstanding CV and transcript, you're not going to get very far. However, if you make it clear that you've looked into the group and can explain why you're interested, you'll have a better chance of getting a response.